# Deploy API redundant backup

Tags: server, webhooks, web-hosting

I've got an API running on a local server with an unstable network. I'm looking to add some cloud-based redundancy, but don't know the best/cheapest way of doing it.

The API receives some data from a webhook and updates a device on the local network.

What I've been brainstorming is a stripped-down version of the API that just keeps the webhook data, pings the main API and if it's up and has received the data does nothing(doesn't keep the data locally if that's the case), but if the Main API is down it sends an email and stores the data then in 12-24 hour intervals re-sends the data until it succeeds(chances are high that the network is down until someone physically resets hardware requires $ to fix that I don't have). Is there a better way of achieving this?

Also, what kind of service would be best for this kind of deployment/what tools are available to help with something like this? It'll be no more than 100 requests per month for sent & received, so I'd like to keep it cheap/free. Although with the 24h timer I don't know the best way of going about doing that. I've used Heroku in the past and I'm aware of its scheduler capabilities, but I haven't used them and wanted more input before investing in that as a solution. The current API can't be deployed as-is and I would likely have to rebuild from scratch to get it working in a cloud environment, so I'd like to have something picked out beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A serverless architecture sounds like the best choice for this situation(i.e. [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)). You could use a managed storage service(i.e. S3) to store the data until you can reach the local API. Anything that involves persistently running services would likely not be cost effective for this use case.

You could either schedule a serverless job or have your local API read from the storage service on a schedule. If your local API can detect these network failures, you could avoid the scheduling entirely and check for updates when connectivity is restored.

I mention AWS, but there are many alternatives(Google Cloud being the most obvious).

Comment: Most internet outages are caused by power outages. The server is located in an old factory with wiring issues. There's a battery backup, but it's only for intermittent outages. The server with the API re-starts, but some of the network hardware fails to do so. So I could still probably do the local network polling, but I'd also like the emails to notify me when the network goes down. I was aware of AWS Lambda, but I'm not actually familiar with serverless architecture or using Lamda. I'll take this as an opportunity to learn those! Thanks for the reply!